# Issues with scraping data off a website using R

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape data off this website using the rvest package.

https://www.footballdb.com/games/index.html?lg=NFL&yr=2021

But when I run my code, I'm getting an error that I don't recognize. I am unsure if I not using the right html class.

here is the html I see when I inspect element
[image]

And here is my code:
#Downloading data - 2021 schedule

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.footballdb.com/games/index.html?lg=NFL&yr=2021"
data <- url %>%
  html_nodes("statistics") %>%
  html_table()
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: You missed `read_html` and try `html_nodes(".statistics")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got error 403 when used your code and its likely incorrect user-agent used or website thinks rvest call is a bot.

Hence used ***httr package*** to setup a user-agent and the following works for your url.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

tmp_user_agent<- 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'
page_response <- GET(url, user_agent(tmp_user_agent))
df_lists<-page_response%>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(".statistics") %>% #classes are queries with dot
  html_table()

df_lists[1] # 2,3,4.....
```

But its advisable to check if the website allows scraping before doing anything large scale or getting their data for any commercial use.